# Disallow implicit conversions to int in function call

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a function:

```
void foo(int n) {
    std::cout << "foo(int)\n";
}
```

which can be called using different arguments, it can be char, double, float etc.:

```
foo(123); // 1
foo('c'); // 2
foo(0.2); // 3
foo(0.2f); // 4
// ...
```

... but I would like to allow only `int` arguments (literal or variable), so that 2,3,4,... above would be illegal. My current solution is to delete those overloads with:

```
void foo(char) = delete;
void foo(float) = delete;
void foo(double) = delete;
```

but this list of overloads can be really long, and always someone can write a class which will implicitly convert to `int` what will allow to use my `int` only function in wrong way, so I found that writing (instead of long explicit list):

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T) = delete;
```

works as expected.

Is there any downside to using template as above? or maybe there are some better ways to aprach this problem?

Comment: What is _wrong_ with non-(truly)`int` parameters? If the values are beyond your function's range, you'd better `throw` exceptions.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius The only difference is, this question is basically asking for potential downsides to the answer given in that question.

Comment: Even if this question is well-written, it doesn't show any research attempt, since searching for the exact title, shows several questions about the same issue.

Comment: I've done the same thing already in real production code. Shorts will not be implicitly converted to int either, though; it is kinda what you want.

Comment: I don't see any downsides. The compiler will favour `foo(int)` over any template version when `int` is used (non-template function preference), and use the deleted template function for all other types.

Comment: @BoBTFish: There is more than one answer given in that question.

Comment: One downside is, that it disallows calling `foo` with `std::reference_wrapper` (i.e. `foo(std::ref(i))`), but that probably does not matter for PODs.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `static_assert` with `std::is_same`:

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T i) {
  static_assert(std::is_same<T, int>::value, "Not int");
  std::cout << "foo(int)\n";
}
```